# i want show my push notification every 24H at 07:00 AM kotlin, how to fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
//notif3 07:00 morning
        val _intent = Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, _intent, 0)
        val alarmManager = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()+ 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent )
```

hello i am newbie in android developer, i want to show my push notification everyday at morning 07:00 AM. right like this code? because when i delete 24*60*60*1000 , push notification whill show everytime
while open app, please help me guys, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager#setExact and AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() is useful for no-repeating notification. For your achieve use Alarmmanager#setRepeating.
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)

Please read the heads up on the doc about the wake-up problems for the battery
(the red Note).

Now, I suggest you to use WorkManager: it is useful to your app to be suitable on every android builds as said its [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager). Of course it allows you to schedule one-time or repeatedly

Hope to have helped :-)

A my code:

```
public long getDelay(){

    int year = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6)),
            month = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5)),
            day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2)),
            hour = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2)),
            minutes = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3));

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month-1, day, hour, minutes);


    long delay = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    long current = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    long trigger = delay-current;
    return trigger;
}
```

Where I call getDelay():

```
    OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class)
            .setInitialDelay(nota.getDelay(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Comment: i use AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()  but if calendar.getTimeInMillis() without + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 it still show while open app sir :O

Comment: Alarmmanager.setRepeating. wrong time sir if i use it

Comment: Alarm Manager and Work Manager methods allow triggerDelay, so you haven't to pass the current time in millis adding more, but pass only the delay. e.g. whenYouWannaInMillis() - currentInMillis().

Comment: how i use AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()  if repeat every 24 H?

Comment: Do not pass currentInMillis() + 24H in millis. Pass only 24H in millis. My last answer above explain why

Comment: can u edit my code in question above sir for right code ?, i am confuse now :(

Comment: Done, but I am gonna post a my code to help you more

Comment: alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 86400000, pendingIntent ) like here sir?

Comment: Exactly! Try it and let me know. Of course, now you need to wait 'till 7a.m. So try with a less delay, then put 24H in millis

Comment: I've just added my code above, read it if you need it

Comment: ok sir thank u very much , i will wait tomorrow :)

Comment: You could try giving 1 min in millis or 30 sec... Then try with 24H. So you won't wait uselessly

Comment: i try and build apk, then install ,but show push every app sir, my code alarmmanager like above then i try add gettimemillis again like this , push notification not show when open :0 : alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()+86400000, pendingIntent )

Comment: then i will waiting for tomorrow :')